# Are questions about Optimal Control Theory on topic?

Tags: discussion

I have a lot of questions pertaining to control theory for fully and underactuated robots with sensor feedback.  The questions draw heavily on the mathematics and physics behind it.

Would these questions be on topic here?

Answer (score 1):

I can't see why they wouldn't be.

From [What topics can I ask about here?](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> **Robotics Stack Exchange** is for professional robotic engineers, hobbyists, researchers and students.
>
> We ask and answer questions about robotics, control systems, control theory, algorithms, actuators and sensors.
>
> We feel the best Robotics questions have links to pertinent datasheets or code, but if your question generally covers …
>
> - a specific robotics design problem
> - the theory and simulation of robotic systems
> - a sensor for a robotic system
> - the writing algorithms for robotic systems
>
> … then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

Just remember that [you should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face.](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)